# Не работает регистрация с devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, аутентификация, devise

Всем привет!
Не работает регистрация с гемом devise_token_auth.

Создаю api на rails. Подключаю гем, создаю модель user, делаю миграцию БД - все ок.

В routes.rb добавляю

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
```

В application_controller.rb

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
    end
```

Далее пробую через Postman послать запрос на регистрацию нового пользователя  POST http://localhost:3000/auth, в теле запроса отдаю параметры:

```
{"email": "email@g.com",
"password": "password12345678",
"password_confirmation": "password12345678"}
```

и получаю ошибку 422 Unprocessable Entity {"success":false,"errors""Please submit proper sign up data in request body."],"status":"error"}

В логах сервера следующее:

```
Started POST "/auth" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-13 13:13:52 +0300
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController#create as /
Filter chain halted as :validate_sign_up_params rendered or redirected
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

пользователь в базе не сохраняется и не регистрируется. 
А если послать данные в url например

```
POST http://localhost:3000/auth?email=abcd@no.co&password=123456789&password_confirmation=123456789
```

то ответ 200 ок, пользователь сохранен в базе и т. д...
Что я делаю не так, подскажите!

Comment: А почему нет before_action в application_controller.rb?

Comment: "Filter chain halted as :validate_sign_up_params rendered or redirected" -- по всей видимости, валидации что-то не понравилось.

Comment: А как выглядят парамсы в логах, когда вы данные в url посылаете? Есть предположение, что в body их надо завернуть в `{ user: }`

Comment: парамсы выглядят так  Started POST "/auth?email=abcd111@no.co&password=[FILTERED]&password_confirmation=[FILTERED]" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-16 00:34:39 +0300
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"email"=>"abcd111@no.co", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}

Comment: @Василиса немного продвинулся, данные надо посылать  в теле запроса в виде: email=qwer@asdf.com, username=example, password=1234567890. Без фигурных скобок и пр. Тогда парамсы выглядят так
  Parameters: {"email"=>"qwer@asdf.com, username=example, password=1234567890"}
  Проблема в том что данные разбиваются не на 3 значения, как надо, а к email приравнивается вся дальнейшая строка. Надо понять как разбить строку на 3 значения

Comment: @Yar-ua, данные должны быть в json формате. Ни разу не пробовала ничего через постман отправить, так что не очень понимаю, как в нём правильно написать

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена тем, что стал использовать Postman под Chromium - под ним данные отправляются корректно. С Postman под Mozilla это не удается.